# Linked tables using Rails Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails Admin to make editing my data a little easier. Here's my question:

Lets say I have a table: "Shirts"

and I have a second table: "Colors"

I've linked the tables (Shirts has_many :colors) - now in Rails Admin, when editing shirts, I'd like a drop down menu to appear for the shirt's color field, gathering available options from the Colors table. Does anyone know if this possible and how I might go about doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I am an idiot - this is clearly done automatically.